# How to export a list of markers as a CSV file and import it into MS Excel

Tags: adobe-audition, exporting

I tried to import a CSV file exported from Adobe Audition into MS Excel, but it doesn't show the end time of the marker.
This is how I export the CSV file from Audition:

1. I select all markers in the list in Audition
2. Right click > Export selected markers
3. In the "Export Markers" window, I select "decimal (mm:ss:ddd)" in "Time format"
4. I save it in a `.csv` file

[image: Adobe Audition Markers List]

[image: Adobe Audition Export CSV windows]

5. I open MS Excel
6. I open a new spreadsheet
7. I select the first cell in the left top corner of the spreadsheet
8. I select "Data" on menu bar
9. I select "From Text" in menu bar of MS Excel
10. The explorer window opens, and I select the `.csv` file exported from Audition
11. In the related window opened in MS Excel, I select the option "Delimited" (Fields separated by comma or tabs)
12. Original file selected is 65001 : Unicode UTF-8
13. I click Forward button
14. I select tab in Delimiters option
15. I click Forward button
16. In data format for column, I select General/Generic
17. I click End/Finish button
18. I have the result as in this screenshot:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

As you can see, the End Time column doesn't exist.
So I don't know really how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column after duration and insert into it the formula `=B2+C2`, fill this down the column which will update the cell reference for multiple rows.